# Why can't I use slice notation to iterate through pages with pyPDF

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice, pypdf

I am running the following code to create a new PDF file with all but the first page of the source PDF:

```
import os
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

inputFile = PdfFileReader(file("/path/to/file", "rb"))
outputPDF = PdfFileWriter()
for page in inputFile.pages[1:]:
    outputPDF.addPage(page)
outputFile = open("/path/to/output/file", "wb")
outputPDF.write(outputFile)
outputFile.close()
```

When I try to run this (Python 2.7.6), the following exception is thrown:

```
for page in inputFile.pages[1:]:
TypeError: sequence indices must be integers
```

If I stop using the slice notation and just use `for page in inputFile.pages:`, I don't get any exception.

Am I doing something wrong, or is just a bug in the pyPdf library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently they haven't set up the `__getitem__` method to work with slices -- only integers.  In your case, you could use `itertools.islice` to get an iterable with the pages that you want.

Comment: Good! I am using this library while trying to teach myself Python, so even though I was feeling it was an issue with the implementation, I wasn't confident about it. I didn't know about the itertools, I will check that out. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/PyPDF2/utils.py#L110), we can see that they only support integers.  This is a bit buggy (I think they should at least support `long`.  Adding support for slices in a clean way isn't quite so obvious -- Although I'm sure it could be worked out...

Comment: I just tried the "itertools.islice" option and it worked perfectly!

Comment: FWIW, I just [forked](https://github.com/mgilson/PyPDF2) and added a [pull request](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/pull/103) to add slicing to the `inputFile.pages`.